# Cannot access webapp deployed in Docker container

Tags: docker, glassfish-4

I'm currently getting into Docker (or trying to), so I set up a little webapp.
I used Eclipse to create a maven-Project, built a .war-file and deployed it (to check if it works) locally on a Glassfish server.
This worked, and I could access the webapp via

```
localhost:8080/myApp
```

Now I created a Dockerfile, built a docker image from that and ran the whole thing via

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 myApp
```

This also works, and

```
docker ps -a
```

shows that a container is running.
However, when I try to access localhost:8080/myApp now, I get

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I tried this with Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

```
docker exec -it <myContainer> bash
```

gives me a shell inside the container (as expected). When I do

```
curl -v localhost:8080/myApp
```

here, I get the output I expect (the page from myApp).

So for me, this means that the container is running, the glassfish server is running inside the container, and myApp has been deployed "properly" to said server, yet still I cannot access myApp from outside the container.

```
docker ps -a
```

yields this, btw:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                       NAMES
9514b1ab6dd0        myApp              "sh /start.sh"      9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        4848/tcp, 8181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   admiring_cori
```

The Dockerfile does of course contain the line

```
EXPOSE 8080
```

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Edit:

These are the contents of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM glassfish:4.0

COPY myApp.war /
COPY start.sh /


EXPOSE 8080

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/start.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/start.sh"]
```

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
/usr/local/glassfish4/bin/asadmin -u admin deploy /myApp.war
/usr/local/glassfish4/bin/asadmin stop-domain
/usr/local/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain --verbose
```

Edit 2:

```
docker logs <container>
```

yields

```
Waiting for domain1 to start ...............
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.
Application deployed with name myApp.
Command deploy executed successfully.
Waiting for the domain to stop .
Command stop-domain executed successfully.
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@2ba2f40 in service registry.
Registry Info:: Total repositories: 1, Total modules = 293
Attached repository: []

[... Registered Modules... all with State = [NEW] or [RESOLVED]]

Found populator: com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml

#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
```

Comment: Please, post your DockerFile so we can see how you started your container

Comment: @GuilhermeUzeda: I edited the question to include the dockerfile

Comment: Did you check the container's log? You can do that with: `docker logs container_id`

Comment: @GuilhermeUzeda I edited again with the log content. I don't see anything fishy (huehue) there.

Comment: You can remove the `EXPOSE 8080` from the Dockerfile, it's just a documentation line. Under which OS are you running this container? It looks more like a configuration issue on the application's side. Since you get the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` it means you **can** access the container, but it refuses to talk to you.

Comment: Do you have access to "http://localhost:8080/"          ?

Comment: @emix I'm running the container under Windows 10. The thing is: When I deploy the same application (i.e. the same .war) locally to a glassfish server, it works just fine (no ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

Comment: @SarathKumar Ah, actually, localhost:8080/ gives me the same error. I didn't have that issue when just deploying the .war directly to glassfish (without docker)...

Comment: The container configuration is fine. The webserver refuses to talk to you. It's a matter of proper configuration so it responds to non-local connections. It works when you deploy the app locally because only then your request origins from the same interface.

Comment: @emix Just to make sure I understand correctly: I need to find a way to configure the glassfish server inside the docker container in such a way that it will talk to me when I access it from outside the container?

Comment: Looks like so exactly. Don't think about containers, your application is oblivous to the fact that it runs inside one. Think about interfaces and different networks. You can verify the container is responding by running the curl in verbose mode: `curl -I -v http://localhost` on your machine. You should always debug connections this way before asking in the first place.

Comment: Anyway, are you [accessing your container properly](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2017/11/06/available-to-windows-10-insiders-today-access-to-published-container-ports-via-localhost127-0-0-1/)?